# manually bootstrapping Angular - not working with 1.3.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

I'm starting off with an empty body element and then dynamically adding HTML that contains an ng-controller attribute. I want to bootstrap the Angular application after that html has been added to the body . This works fine with angular 1.0 but not with 1.3.8. Any ideas why?

```
require(['angular'], function(angular){
  'use strict';


  buildDom();

  function buildDom(){
    $('body').append('<div role="tabpanel" ng-controller="WelcomeController"><span>{{greeting}}</span></div>');
  }



  var app = angular.module('demo', []);

  app.controller('WelcomeController', function($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Welcome!';
  });

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ["demo"]);
  });

});
```

end result - I see {{greeting}} and not Welcome!

Comment: Where is `GroupsService` defined? What error do you see int he console?

Comment: What's not working?  What errors do you see?  Does it matter that you call `buildDom()` before you define it?

Comment: sorry, the GroupsService is not there. I'll edit the code

Comment: Marc - no errors are thrown and and i see is {{greeting}} . I want to see Welcome! 
it doesnt matter if you call buildDom before defining it - its hoisted to the top

Answer (score 0):

right way of bootstrapping angularjs and requirejs is something like:

```
'use strict';

require.config({    
    baseUrl: 'js/',
    deps: ['jquery'],

    paths: {
        jquery: '../lib/jquery.min',
        angular: '../lib/angular.min'
    },  

    shim: {     
        'angular': {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            'exports': 'angular'
        }
    },  
    priority: [
        'angular'
    ]

});

//https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap
window.name = 'NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!';

require([
    'angular',
    'app'
], function(angular, app) {
    'use strict';
    var $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);  
    angular.element().ready(function() {                
        angular.resumeBootstrap([app['name']]);
    });
});
```

now you should have a separate file called app.js :

```
define([
    'angular',
    'services',
    'directives',
    'controllers'
    ], function (angular) {
        'use strict';

        return angular.module('myapp', [
            'myapp.services',
            'myapp.directives',
            'myapp.controllers'
        ]);     
});
```

Then you should have on each file (services.js, directives.js and controllers.js) each one of your angular components declared.